# Creating a window in pygame without displaying it

Tags: python-2.7, pygame

I create a screen in pygame using:

```
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width,height))
```

Then I draw 200 random gray scale circles on it and save the screen as an image. (I need to save this screen as an image so I can compare it to a target image later on):

```
pygame.image.save(screen, "Circles.png")
```

Now, I need to randomly change different parameters of different circles by putting the numpy array that contains the circle parameters for all the circles in a loop with a big number as its iteration value.

And I need to redraw the mutated circles on a screen (at the end of each iteration) and save that screen as a png image again.

Now the problem is, every time I use `pygame.display.set_mode((width,height))` it opens up the display window and it significantly slows down my program.

I would like to create a screen and save it in a variable but don't need to display that screen at each iteration. I haven't been able to figure out what command to use to avoid displaying the screen.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: I'm curious as to why you're continuously creating new displays as opposed to modifying the existing one. Doing it this way would also inhibit the display's ability to update unless you call display's update function.

Comment: I'm new to python and pygame and that's the best I could come up with. I'm sure there are better ways of writing this code. But basically what I need is to change some of the parameters of some of the circles on the screen at each iteration and then save the screen as an image. Then get the pixel values of that image to compare them to the pixel values of a target image and calculate the fitness value.

Comment: @Mary: As oxrock posted you don´t need to *create* a *new* screen surface every iteration. For a quick and dirty approach you could fill your screen (call [`screen.fill()`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.fill)), draw the circles and update the *whole* screen using PyGames [`pygame.display.flip()`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip) method. After that you can save the screen as an image.  Hope this helps :)

Comment: @oxrock and elegent : I put pygame.display.flip() outside the loop. This way I update my screen after all the modifications to the circles are done as opposed to updating it after each modification. Thanks very much for the hint. My program runs much faster now but I'm still looking for a way to completely stop the screen from popping up and only save it as an image and then extract the pixel values from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably end up using something like this. This will still popup a screen but it will be tiny and never updated.

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

def circle_drawing(surf):
    pass
    #your circle drawing function using passed in surface

DISPLAY = (1, 1)
DEPTH = 32
FLAGS = 0
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(DISPLAY, FLAGS, DEPTH)
work_surface  = pygame.Surface((500,500))
count = 0
while True:
    ws = circle_drawing(work_surface.copy())
    pygame.image.save(ws, "circles_" + str(count)+".png")
    count +=1
```

Comment: I needed transparent circles so I had to draw each circle on a separate surface and then blit that surface onto this new surface instead of onto the screen but it worked! I ran it for 50 iterations and was pretty fast. Now I need to implement the rest of the code and run it for 150,000 iterations or so. I will post the results here. Thanks very much for your help!

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want a window to appear, try creating the surface like this:

```
screen = pygame.Surface((width,height))
```

Then you can draw your circles on this surface and save it the same way as you did before. As others have said, clear the surface with the fill() method.

Comment: afaik you can't create any surfaces in pygame until the display surface is configured. Going off memory on this though, not 100%

Comment: You can create surfaces, but there are some limitations, convert() doesn't work for example. Drawing circles and saving the images should work though.